# Simple Android SharedPreferences Implementation: Method Failure - All Values Are Null

Tags: android, string, null, sharedpreferences

I'm attempting to null check several values in my source code and it appears they are all returning null. I should be able to use these value in my new class due to my SharedPreferences implementation but it appears it is not working. (I appear to be overlooking something simple.)

Startpoint Class SharedPreferences Implementation:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("name",true);
    editor.putBoolean("cap",true);
    editor.putBoolean("code",true);
    editor.putBoolean("time",true);
    editor.putBoolean("ssid",true);
    editor.commit();
```

Endpoint Class SharedPreferences Implementation:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
   if (new == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Broken Value! Debug! Debug!"); 
    prefs.getBoolean("new", true);
    prefs.getBoolean("user", true);
    prefs.getBoolean("name", true);
    prefs.getBoolean("data", true);
    prefs.getBoolean("login", true);
    editor.commit();
```

The values in my endpoint are showing as null when I check them - any idea why? I believe they should n't be null due to my implementation of SharedPreferences but they are all still returning null. (I could have sworn I implemented this correctly - I have no idea why I cannot retrieve these values - I believe everything should be functioning - but strangely: it is not.)

First Attempt At Solution Provided:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
            prefs.getBoolean("name", true);
            prefs.getBoolean("cap", true);
            prefs.getBoolean("code", true);
            prefs.getBoolean("time", true);
            prefs.getBoolean("ssid", true);
            editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the SharedPreferences, try this instead:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Where `PREFS_NAME`is the name you give to the file.

Also you can't do this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
prefs.getBoolean("new", true);
```

Since the Editor class doesn't have that method... Instead you should use your `prefs` variable to get the values.

And take a look at what are you saving and restoring... the only value that is in both cases is the "name", so the others will be false.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
String NDEF_PREF = "prefs";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.getBoolean("name", true);
prefs.getBoolean("cap", true);
prefs.getBoolean("code", true);
prefs.getBoolean("time", true);
prefs.getBoolean("ssid", true);
```

Comment: Can you let me know if my edit above looks correct? I'm getting an error stating NDEF_PREF cannot be resolved to a variable and when I attempt to null check it using:  if (name == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Broken Value! Debug! Debug!");

I get "name cannot be resolved to a variable" before I even attempt to run it through logcat

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to nullcheck these values by using:  if (name == null) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Broken Value! Debug! Debug!");

I'm getting "name cannot be resolved to a variable" when attempting to do so - does that mean I didn't implement something correctly - or is it supposed to function like this?

Comment: Also - do I need any sort of commit statement at the end?